# Multisite Permutation with Repetition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assume you have the word 'abab'. I want to find permutation of size 2 for the word without duplication. The answer is clearly $2!=2$. However, I am struggling with finding a generalize from.

### My Attempt

First, we know the size of the word is 4. Remove the duplication letters from the word $\frac{4!}{2!2!}=3!=6$. Then, find the permutation of size 2 $\frac{3!}{(3-2)!}$. Obviously this didn't work. Is there a way to composite permutation operations together?

Many thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: Permutation of size two are aa, ab, ba and bb?

Comment: Sorry I fixed the question. It is without duplication, i.e. only ab, ba

Answer (score 0):

First find out the distinct letters in it, say 'abcd' then for first letter we have 4 options, for second we have three, for third we have 2 ...